# How to create correctly the following design

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

So the design that i want is similar to this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bGRS.png)

What i have done so far is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Article Title"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="10/11/2017"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEXT"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't undesrtand how can i make the same ui using`LinearLayout`.
I'm using `LinearLayout` so that i can use it with `recyclerView` later on, this design will be a list, can some one tell me what am i doing wrong?

Anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: Link requires login - please add a screenshot instead

Comment: @Ridcully added a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use LinearLayout for RecyclerView items. You can use any layout for that.